# Attempted separation of $(\nu \nabla^2\circ \nabla^2 - s \nabla^2)\eta(x,y,z)=0$ into two equations.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fluid-dynamics

The subject material of this question is relevant to Rayleigh-Benard convection and the Boussinesq equations. It also appears relevant to deriving what people call an amplitude equation.

I am trying to go through separating
 $$(\nu \nabla^2\circ \nabla^2 - s \nabla^2)\eta(x,y,z)=0        \tag{1}$$
by using the separation of variables approach, $\nu$ and $s$ are constants.

So, I am trying to find equations for the possible $f$ and $g$ in
 $$(\nu \nabla^2\circ \nabla^2 - s \nabla^2)f(x,y)g(z)=0          \tag{2}$$

It looks to me, now , as if the separation cannot be performed but based upon the Spiegel lecture I mention, it looked as if the separated equations should be

\begin{align}
 \nabla_1^2f(x,y)&=-k^2         \\
[s-\nu(D^2-k^2)]\circ(D^2-k^2)g(z)&=0
\end{align}
where
\begin{align}\nabla_1^2&= \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}  +  \frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}\\
D^2&= \frac{\partial^2}{\partial z^2}
\end{align}
BUT I am having trouble working this through. Might anyone help with this?

OTHER INFORMATION

See 'Dissipative Boussinesq Dynamics' by Edward A Spiegel,  at

http://www.dtic.mil/docs/citations/ADA114366

In particular, see Equation (6), pg. 34 of the PDF.

According to the above lecture, starting from the Boussinesq approximation and applying what has been termed a linearization it is possible to derive an equation for a function representing the vertical vorticity $\zeta(x,y,z,t)$ which is given as
$$(\partial_t  - \nu \nabla^2)\circ \nabla^2\zeta(x,y,z,t)=0$$

Looking for solutions of the form
$$\zeta\propto e^{st}g_s(x,y,z)$$
and substitution of this into the partial differential equation, we have

\begin{align}
(\partial_t  - \nu \nabla^2)\circ \nabla^2e^{st}g_s(x,y,z)&=0\\
( \partial_t e^{st}\nabla^2    -     \nu e^{st}  \nabla^2 \circ \nabla^2 )g_s&=0\\
( \partial_t e^{st}\nabla^2 g_s   -     \nu e^{st}  \nabla^2 \circ \nabla^2 g_s )&=0\\
\left(      \frac{ \partial_t e^{st}\nabla^2 g_s  }  { \nu e^{st} \nabla^2 g_s   }   -  \frac{ \nu e^{st}  \nabla^2 \circ \nabla^2 g_s }{ \nu e^{st} \nabla^2 g_s     } \right)&=0\\ 
\left(      \frac{ \partial_t e^{st}  }  { \nu e^{st}    }   -  \frac{   \nabla^2 \circ \nabla^2 g_s }{  \nabla^2 g_s     } \right)&=0\\
\left(      \frac{ \partial_t e^{st}  }  {  e^{st}    }   -  \frac{ \nu  \nabla^2 \circ \nabla^2 g_s }{  \nabla^2 g_s     } \right)&=0\\
 \frac{ \partial_t e^{st} }  {  e^{st}    }   &= \frac{ \nu  \nabla^2 \circ \nabla^2 g_s }{  \nabla^2 g_s     } =C
\end{align}

hence
\begin{align}
  \partial_t e^{st}  &= C e^{st} \\
  \nu  \nabla^2 \circ \nabla^2 g_s     &  =C \nabla^2 g_s\\   
\end{align}

From the above, the separation constant $C$ must equal $s$, so our seprarated equations may be written

\begin{align}
  \partial_t e^{st}  &= s e^{st} \\
   (\nu  \nabla^2 \circ \nabla^2  -s \nabla^2 )   g_s (x,y,z)   &  = 0\\     
\end{align}

Putting $g_s(x,y,z)=\eta(x,y,z)$, in the above, gives (1).

To separate $\eta(x,y,z)$ such that $\eta(x,y,z)=f(x,y)g(z)$ we need to reexpress
$$   (\nu  \nabla^2 \circ \nabla^2  -s \nabla^2 )   \eta(x,y,z)    = 0  $$
as

(  terms involving only x and y ) + (  terms involving only z ) = 0

Put
\begin{align}
\nabla_1^2&= \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}  +  \frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}\\
D^2&= \frac{\partial^2}{\partial z^2}\\
\text{so }\nabla^2&=\nabla_1^2+D^2\\
\end{align}

Now trying to find consistent equations for the possible $f$ and $g$ in
$$(\nu \nabla^2\circ \nabla^2 - s \nabla^2)f(x,y)g(z)=0          $$
we must have

\begin{align}
(\nu   (\nabla_1^2+D^2)   \circ  (\nabla_1^2+D^2)       - s   (\nabla_1^2+D^2)      )f(x,y)g(z)&=0          \\
(     \nabla_1^2  \circ  \nabla_1^2  +  
2 \nabla_1^2   \circ  D^2
+D^2   \circ  D^2  ) fg
   - \frac{s} {\nu}  \nabla_1^2fg - \frac{s} {\nu}D^2    fg&=0          \\
\end{align}

Using the following,
\begin{align}
 \nabla_1^2f(x,y)&=-k^2         \\
\text {we have ; }
(  -2 k^2      D^2 g
+D^2   \circ  D^2  fg)
   + k^2\frac{s} {\nu}  g - \frac{s} {\nu}D^2    fg&=0          \\
(  - \frac{2 k^2}{f}      D^2 g
+D^2   \circ  D^2  g)
   +\frac{ k^2}{f} \frac{s} {\nu}  g - \frac{s} {\nu}D^2 g&=0          \\
\end{align}

This is as far as I get, perhaps there is an error in Spiegel's lecture and the separation cannot be performed? Perhaps $f$ can be approximated as equal to one or put equal to zero, for the purposes of the lecture material?

Answer (score 1):

Using the following condition, should lead to a separation into two equations.

$$ \nabla_1^2f(x,y)=-k^2 f(x,y)        $$

It looks as if the separated equations can be written as
\begin{align}
\nabla_1^2f(x,y)&=-k^2 f(x,y)        \\
[s-\nu(D^2-k^2)](D^2-k^2)g(z)&=0
\end{align}
where
\begin{align}
\nabla_1^2&= \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}  +  \frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}\\
D^2&= \frac{\partial^2}{\partial z^2}
\end{align}